# Inequality dealing with area and sides of a triangle

Tags: triangles, geometric-inequalities

I have to prove that:

$$\frac{a^6}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^6}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{c^6}{a^2+b^2}\geq 8S^2$$
$a$, $b$, $c$ are the sides of a triangle, and $S$ its area.

I tried using the Sine Theorem, different  area formulas, and AM-GM but didn't get anywhere.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746046 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1337422p7243910

Comment: Presumably, you have to use Heron's formula for the area in terms of the sides.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll see if I can work with these.

Comment: Heron seems to work since it gets rid of the square root and a few other things. Considering the inequality from the other questions, I am left with $abc\geq(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)$ which is quite easy if I assume $a\geq b\geq c$. Now lets see if I understand the proof from those questions.

Comment: Ok, I have found another question about that inequality(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660230/olympiad-inequalities?r=SearchResults) and the answer there seems pretty clear. Thank you for the help :) If anyone wants to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How do I show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac {a^6}{b^2 + c^2} \ge \frac {abc(a + b + c)}2?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746046/how-do-i-show-that-sum-cyc-frac-a6b2-c2-ge-frac-abca-b-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), we can show that
$$\frac {a^6}{b^2 + c^2} + \frac {b^6}{c^2 + a^2} + \frac {c^6}{a^2 + b^2} \ge \frac {abc(a + b + c)}2.$$
For your question, use Heron's formula:
$$S=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
$$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$
So the right hand side of the inequality $8S^2$ can be turned into
$$8\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{b+c-a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+c-b}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)$$
Now, what's left is to prove
$$\frac {abc(a + b + c)}2\geq\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)$$
Or
$$abc\geq(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)$$,
which is true if we let $a\geq b\geq c$

So we are left with
$$\frac {a^6}{b^2 + c^2} + \frac {b^6}{c^2 + a^2} + \frac {c^6}{a^2 + b^2} \ge \frac {abc(a + b + c)}2\geq 8S^2$$